# Comparing Mathias forcing notions relative to various filters

Tags: lo.logic, forcing, ultrafilters, cardinal-characteristics, filters

Let $\mathcal F$ be a (non-principle, non trivial, ...) filter on $\omega$. The *Mathias Forcing* relative to $\mathcal F$ is the forcing notion $\mathbb M(\mathcal F)$ consisting of pairs $(s, X)$ with $s$ a finite set of natural numbers, $X \in \mathcal F$ and ${\rm min}(X) > {\rm max}(s)$ and the relation $(s, X) \leq (t, Y)$ if and only if $s \supseteq t$, $X \subseteq Y$ and $s \setminus t \subseteq Y$. Obviously this forcing is ccc (in fact $\sigma$-centered) regardless of the choice of filter. If $G \subseteq \mathbb M(\mathcal F)$ is generic then the union of the first components is a pseudo intersection of the filter $\mathcal F$ which is co-constructible with $G$. This (family of) forcing notion(s) is well studied.

I am interested in how $\mathbb M (\mathcal F)$ and $\mathbb M (\mathcal G)$ are relate for different filters $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$, particularly in the cases where neither are ultrafilters. Essentially I have two questions:

1. Suppose $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal G$. Clearly forcing with $\mathbb M(\mathcal G)$ addes a pseudo intersection to $\mathcal F$. Under what conditions is this pseudointersection also generic for $\mathbb M(\mathcal F)$?
2. Essentially the same as 1 but in a more specialized context, namely when $\mathcal G$ is generated by $\mathcal F$ and some new reals added by some (auxilary) forcing. More concretely: Suppose $\mathbb P$ is a forcing notion adding some reals $\{\dot{X}_i\}_{i \in I} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ (the index set is not important - it could be finite or even one) and $\mathcal F$ is a filter so that $\Vdash_\mathbb P$ ``$\mathcal F \cup \{\dot{X}_i\}_{i \in I}$ generates a filter". Then, if $G \subseteq V$ is $\mathbb P$-generic we can define in $V[G]$ the forcing $\mathbb M(\langle \mathcal F \cup \{\dot{X}^G_i\}_{i \in I}\rangle)$ where $\langle \mathcal F \cup \{\dot{X}^G_i\}_{i \in I}\rangle$ is the filter generated by $\mathcal F \cup \{\dot{X}^G_i\}_{i \in I}$. Under what conditions does $\mathbb M(\langle \mathcal F \cup \{\dot{X}^G_i\}_{i \in I}\rangle)$ add a generic for $\mathbb M(\mathcal F)$? In other words, when does $\mathbb M (\mathcal F)$ completely embed into $\mathbb M(\langle \mathcal F \cup \{\dot{X}^G_i\}_{i \in I}\rangle)$?

As a remark for 2, I know this can happen sometimes (and is the motivation for this question) - namely if $\mathcal F$ is any filter, $\mathbb P$ is Cohen forcing and we want to add the generic Cohen real to $\mathcal F$. Also if $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter in $V$ and we extend $\mathcal F$ to an ultrafilter in $V[G]$ I am fairly sure this happens as well (I know it's true for Laver forcing relative to filters and I believe the proof goes through for Mathias forcing almost verbatim though I haven't checked the details).

More generally any information/sources on how Mathias forcing relative to various filters, especially which are not ultra, would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The following might be useful, note that it talks about Mathias forcing as well: 
 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800729190018H

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Thanks! I'll check it out.